# Loading Octave data set csv

Tags: csv, octave

Good Morning All!
Please forgive me I am a long time MATLAB user, first time Octave user. I have a CSV file with some sample data, the trouble is I am struggling to load the csv.  The first 3 columns are categorical data i.e. column 1 has values of either men or women, column 2 gives an age group, i.e. 15-20, 30-40 and the 4th gives the frequency.  I've tried CSVread, dataframe and I've tried loading it in using the IO package.

I'm a windows user. I have Octave 3.6.4 installed and an older version of IO installed 1.2.5.

Does anyone know a quick way to load this csv so that octave recognises that the first 3 columns are strings and the last is numeric

Thanks so much

James

My apologies, I am unaware how to upload the csv but I can give you a sample here:

```
women   18-23   no/little   26
women   18-23   important   12
women   18-23   very important  7
women   24-40   no/little   9
women   24-40   important   21
women   24-40   very important  15
women   > 40    no/little   5
women   > 40    important   14
women   > 40    very important  41
 men    18-23   no/little   40
 men    18-23   important   17
 men    18-23   very important  8
 men    24-40   no/little   17
 men    24-40   important   15
 men    24-40   very important  12
 men    > 40    no/little   8
 men    > 40    important   15
 men    > 40    very important  18
```

Comment: Please provide us the CSV file you're trying to read or a snippet of it. Also consider [GNU Octave 3.8](http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/).

Comment: I'm still not quite sure how to install the latest version without using the windows setup.  I am using this at work so it is difficult to install programs without going through a process with the IT dept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A low-level solution with `textread` assuming the CSV delimiter is a <kbd>TAB</kbd>:

```
[gender,age,rank,freq] = textread("foo.csv", "%s%s%s%d", "delimiter", "\t")
```